# R if function still executed even if condition evaluated to false

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm using iris dataset.

Ran the following code:

```
functionq3 <- function(x) {
  if(x[['Sepal.Length']] > 5) {
    return("greater than 5") 
  }
  else {
    return("less than 5") 
  }
}
outputq3 <- apply(iris,1,functionq3)
print(outputq3)
```

It returns "greater than 5" even if the value is 5. I'm expecting "less than 5". What's going wrong?

Comment: Your description 'less than 5' is erroneous; it should be 'less than or equal to 5' or words to that effect.  That doesn't explain what you are seeing though.

Comment: ````apply```` converts all numeric in ````iris```` to character, and this has to do with the ````>```` because ````"5.0" > 5```` returns TRUE.

Comment: Better as a comment not an answer*: more efficient code that provides the correct results would be using the ifelse function: `ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length > 5, "greater than 5", "less than or equal to 5")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` coerces all the elements in the `iris` data frame to character. Then in your function, comparison operator `>` coerces the numeric 5 on the RHS of `x[['Sepal.Length']] > 5` to character "5".

So the real comparison of "5.0" (in `iris[['Sepal.Length']]`) and 5 is `"5.0" > "5"`. This comparison depend on how the character strings "5.0" and "5" are encoded.

See ?Comparison

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the
> strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use ...
>
> ... If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
> coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
> being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.